# MDX Queries with scope and filter function

Tags: mdx

I am writing one MDX query where I need to filter out some records on the basis of 2 attributes.

Now am getting data in below format so I need to filter out some records.

```
AAA P   B
AB  1   0-6
AA  2   6-12 month
AC  3   >12
AF  2   >12
AB  1   6-12 month
AG  3   >12 month
```

So I want to filter out the records on below conditions.

```
(p =1 AND B='0-6') OR (P=2 AND B='6-12 Months') OR (p=3 AND B = '> months')
```

Can you please help me to add this filters using MDX.

Thanks in advance..

Regards,

Sagar

Comment: can you please add the MDX you have attempted

Answer (score 0):

It's too little information, but what's wrong with the following MDX:

```
case 
   when [Measures].[P] = 1 
   and [Measures].[B] = '0-6'
   then 1
   when [Measures].[P] = 2
   and [Measures].[B] = '6-12 Months'
   then 1
   when [Measures].[P] = 3
   and [Measures].[B] = '> months'
   then 1
   else null
end
```